# How to show unique data from multiple tables in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have three different data to show through php as I shown below

I need to show data as shown in below image.
[image]
But when i use foreach loop to show them, then the results looks like this

[image]

```
foreach($GetSectionwiseAttempted as $gsa) { 
    foreach($GetSectionwiseCorrect as $gsc) {
        foreach($GetSectionwiseTimeSpent as $gst) { 
            $markp_q = '';
            $penaltyp_q = '';
            $full_mark = '';
            $correct_ans = $gsc['CORRECT'];
            $total_attempt = $gsa['total_attempted'];
            $SC_DETAILS = showSub_CourseDetails($paperID);

            foreach($SC_DETAILS as $sc) {
                $markp_q = $sc['markp_q'];
                $penaltyp_q = $sc['penaltyp_q'];
                $full_mark = $sc['full_mark'];
            }
            $wrong_ans = $total_attempt-$correct_ans;
            $marks_got = ($correct_ans*$markp_q)-($wrong_ans*$penaltyp_q);
            ?>
            <?php echo   $gsa['sub_name'];?>    </font>
            <?php echo $marks_got; ?><?php echo $gsa['total_attempted'];?>
            <?php echo $gsc['CORRECT'];?>
            <?php $last_active = $gst['time_spent'];

            $minutes = floor($last_active / 60);
            $seconds = $last_active % 60;

            if ($minutes > 0) {
                echo $minutes . 'minutes';
            }

            if ($seconds > 0) {
                if ($minutes > 0) {
                    echo "and ";
                }
                echo $seconds . 'seconds';
            }
        }
    }
} 
?>
```

Comment: Please add code you have tries so far instead of images

Comment: you can use joins for it but first tell what actually you want to fetch from the tables.

Comment: in each for loop the one data is common and the 2nd column data is unique and i need to show the unique data with common data in a loop but when i write the above code the same data is repeated multiple times